# Hidden div popup doesn't appear after clicking with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

consider this code:

```
from parsel import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.bizbuysell.com/buy/')

btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Select Categories"]')

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(btn).click(btn).perform()

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="toggleAll"]'))).click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Save Changes"]').click()

driver.quit()
```

The popup modal dialog (it's not an iframe) when clicking on the "Select Categories" a href link, doesn't appear. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the button as:

```
btn=WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Select Categories"]')))
```

**Edit:**
See if starting the driver page maximized helps.

```
options=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks but it din't work, still the timeout error without a message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape.py", line 24, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[@class="toggleAll"]'))).click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Strange..ran the whole script successfully, with only that line changed. Try waiting for longer so change the 5 to 10 or 20, if the page loads slower at your end for whatever reason.

Comment: Same negative result. Which python3 and Selenium version do you have?

Comment: python 3.6, selenium 3.141. I'd be very surprised if that makes any difference. Check my answer edit for another idea.

Comment: Thanks for following this matter, mate. Nope, the window appears maximized but still the popup doesn't appear and I get the same timeout message.

Same versions... mistery

Comment: I forgot to say I'm using Linux. Are you using it as well?

Comment: Yep with geckdriver on Linux Mint Debian Edition. The same negative result. I can the button is clicked because it changes the background color and then bam, the above error message appears. I'm really puzzled...